# Azure network output increase significantly without any reason

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

there is a VM in azure and running an IIS.
I have parsed all IIS logfiles and the whole outgoing traffic over last 7 days is about 2GB. The graphic show me traffic in amount 5-10 GB a day within the last seven days.

What is going on here?
Are there other known azure services increasing network traffic by default?
I guess I should sniff my machine to see if there are other services increasing my outgoing traffic.

[image: increasing network traffic outgoing]

Comment: Network traffic graph shows traffic at network card level, not IIS only. Does you IIS connect a backend database or storage?  Do other processes on your VM make high data traffic?  Suggestion: connect to your VM and monitor network traffic for a couple of hours using performance monitor.

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino thank you for the hint. Trace is running now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were "Diagnostics settings" enabled within my virtual machine. After disabling this, my traffic is going back to the regular amount.